# sql server reading with nolock causes wait for same query executed in parallel

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core

I'm actually facing performance issue with some data I'm displaying on my homepage.

I have a query running some select with CTE and for every table I added a WITH (NOLOCK) to be sure that the reading don't block anything.

My query is executing in 4-5 seconds but if I open 4 swagger on my backend API (.NET Core 2.2) and run the query, it will takes 17-19 seconds ...

I don't understand where to look for. Why reading operation with nolock would not be able to run in parallel ? I'm accessing the same data. It's typically a common case no ? A same dashboard of data for user that comes to your website at the same time ...

I used DMV query to check the status during the parallel queries:

```
session_id status command

57 running SELECT

59 runnable   SELECT

60 running    SELECT

64 running    SELECT

66 running    SELECT

67 runnable   SELECT

75 runnable   SELECT

78 runnable   SELECT
```

Any idea?

Adding DMV stats for the query:

```
ExecCount   CpuPerExec  CpuTotal    IOPerExec   IOTotal AvgElapsedTime  AvgWaitTime AvgRowCount

9   2000898 18008084    13935   125422  2534106 533208  330
```

**Edits (Additional information on connection)**

I'm using the following code to open my connection

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringBuilder(dbName));
await con.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
con.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted).Commit();
```

Comment: Are you performing any DDL operation(index rebuild, schema changes)? NOLOCK uses Schema-Stability lock.

Comment: Second case it may not be related the NOLOCK but the query ([Slow in application fast in SSMS](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html))

Comment: Why are you thinking the performance issue is caused by locking? Have a look  at wait statistics for the "slow" session ( `sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats` ) to determine the real cause.

Comment: I don't performing ddl operation neither update/insert/delete. It's only reading query @LukaszSzozda

Comment: @Jerome2606 I guess you are using parametrized query and has parameter sniffing issues

Comment: *"and for every table I added a WITH (NOLOCK) to be sure that the reading don't block anything"* That isn't really what `NOLOCK` does, and use of it everywhere normally implies a far larger problem. [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda could you elaborate the parameter sniffing issues ? Yes I'm using parametrized query

Comment: @Jerome2606 Please refer to link from my second comment

Comment: Try with ```set transaction isolation level read uncommitted```. Just a little observation 4-5s * 4 = 16*20s. If your query take 100% of resource (CPU, RAM,..), it's a predictable behavior.

Comment: Actually I don't think it is a sniffing problem, if I understood, it would mean that a second evaluation of the query can be slow. Here is I execute 10 times the same query one by one it will take 4-5 seconds each. If I launch 4 queries at the same time (same parameters, same SQL query) it takes 17-19 seconds each.

Comment: @Tohm does SQL server not able to read in parallel the data ? If I take a simple example in my office, I'm able to read an excel file on a network disk at the same time than my colleague. I already use read uncomitted.

Comment: @Jerome2606 of course sql server can execute several query in parallel. But if one query take all cpu resource, two execution of this query will take twice the time. You can try with a ```Top 100``` and note an performance difference . Datas come from excel sheet ? (with ```OPENROWSET``` ?) In this case it would be more efficient to import the data into a real SQL table

Comment: Your last line of code is very odd.  Why do you open a transaction and commit it in the same line?  Not sure if this has anything to do with your problem, but it's odd at least.

Comment: @PhilSandler: it's a weird and disturbing way to issue a `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` statement (which makes any use of an explicit `NOLOCK` unnecessary, by the way) without actually issuing that statement explicitly. Not to be recommended, because once you set the transaction isolation level to something other than the default `READ COMMITTED` even once, for a single connection, you have to do it consistently for all connections, since this setting persists across pooling and you'll never know what you'll end up with.

Comment: @Tohm it is not using full CPU I test it locally but I have the same behavior on my production server which is a good server. Excel file was just a metaphore. I'm using a SQL Server table. I'm using read uncomitted everywhere. And yes in theory I should not have to add with (nolock). And event with all these I need to wait for reading :(

Comment: @PhilSandler Indeed, your request has a curious behavior. Your CTE part is recursive ?  You can try to limit recursivity ```with OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10)```.Then you should check if there are any aberrations in execution plan  b.e. with ```SET SHOWPLAN_ALL```

Comment: @Tohm I think you may have tagged the wrong person?

Comment: @Jerome2606 Indeed, your request has a curious behavior. Your CTE part is recursive ? You can try to limit recursivity with OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10).Then you should check if there are any aberrations in execution plan b.e. with SET SHOWPLAN_ALL

Comment: @PhilSandler  sorry bad autocompletion :)

Comment: @Tohm no my CTE is not recursive. I will make some test to get the execution plan